# How to keep a bound service running during application's life-cycle?

Tags: java, android, service, android-lifecycle

I start and bind to a `Service` like this inside my `MainActivity.java`:

```
   @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebSocket.class);
        bindService(intent, webSocket_connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

*I don't call `startService(intent)` at all inside my applicaiton*

My question, how to ensure that the bound service will keep running during my application's life-cycle? How to restart it in case it gets killed by the system, (if the main application is still running)?

Comment: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/who-lives-and-who-dies-process-priorities-on-android-cb151f39044f see foregound process

Answer (score 0):

By behavior a Bound service life span is until the last component binds to it calls unbind or destroy. 
Multiple components can bind to the service at once, but when all of them unbind, the service is destroyed.

So in your case you need Service to run During Application Lifecycle . You can bind Service in your very first `Activity` which is your Home Activity per say and then bind subsequently when further Activities Open(only if required).. So the Last Activity to be close when your APP is close is Home Activity it will unbind and the service will stop because it was the last component bounded .

**Note->** Make sure you call bind and unbind proper lifecycle methods inside Activity.. like `onCreate`->`onDestroy()` or `onStart()`->`onStop()`.

Comment: I understand there should be no situation a bound service will be terminated while the calling activity is still running and have not called `unbind`?

Comment: Yeah until the Activity is in foreground because it has foreground priority . Please go through the link above posted in comments by  Raghunandan ..

Answer (score 0):

If you what you really want is to open and close a WebSocket whenever your Activity (or your Application) is starts and stops you have to check Tinder's library for webSocket called 'Scarlet', which registers your webSocket connection to a lifecycle

You can find it here

https://github.com/Tinder/Scarlet